# Criar uma lista com data, nomes de alunos e se esta presente ou ausente usando JAVA

Tags: java

Estava pensando em algo assim.....looping não ocorre

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chamada {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner imput = new Scanner(System.in);

        String data[] = {"26/08/2021", "27/08/2021", "28/08/2021"};
        String aluno[] = {"Aline", "Beto", "marcela"};

        String[][] chamada = new String[data.length][aluno.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Lista de presença do dia " + data[i]);
            for (int x = 0; x < aluno.length; x++) {
                System.out.println(aluno[x] + " esta presente");
                chamada[i][x] = imput.nextLine();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá...desde de já muito obrigado!!!! Eu não vou precisar percorrer um for com alunos.lenght?

Answer (score 0):

Espere, por que você está colocando um for dentro do outro, sendo que ambos vão executar 3x? Isso geraria 12 saídas.
Além disso, você não colocou nenhuma condição para determinar se está presente ou não.
Tente algo mais simples, arrays bidimensionais são desnecessários nesse caso:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lista {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sx = new Scanner(System.in);

        String dia[] = {"01/01/2021", "02/01/2021", "03/01/2021"};
        String alunos[] = {"fulano", "clicano", "deltano"};

        String chamada[] = new String[dia.length][alunos.length];

        sx.close();

        for(int i = 0; i < dia.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Chamada do dia " + dia[i]);
            System.out.println("Aluno " + alunos[i] + " está presente?(sim/não)");
            String yn = sx.next();
            if(yn.equals("sim")){
                System.out.println("Ok");

            }else{
                System.out.println("Ok, falta marcada");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Para qualquer mod que esteja lendo, só queria avisar que respondi na medida do possível com as poucas informações que foram passadas. Sei que o autor da pergunta é (provavelmente) iniciante, e como eu também sou, resolvi compartilhar um pouco do meu humilde conhecimento.